# Graph Beta Channel Get Messages returns "Forbidden"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When reading Teams channel messages with Graph, I am getting a "Forbidden" error. Note: this started last week regardless of the channel messages that were created with the Teams UI (Web) or Graph. To mitigate the problem I need to remove the Graph OAuth user from the team using PowerShell:

(1)Remove-TeamUser,
(2)remove-unifiedgrouplinks for "owner",
(3)remove-unifiedgrouplinks for "member",
(4)add-teamuser with role "owner".

It feels like the problem is that the OAuth admin, used to create the team, is both "Member" and "Owner" with UnifiedGroupLinks.

Comment: Do you following permission consented by admin Group.ReadWrite.All?

Comment: Yes - in our tool and with the Graph Explorer.

Comment: Could you please send us the request body so we can check?

Comment: I will try to recreate today with a new instance.